# Can't survive the night

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I'm playing latest version of better than wolves mod for Minecraft on easy difficulty and can not survive a single night. What am I doing wrong? I'm not dying of hunger, but from mobs. Mostly archers. And there doesn't seem to be enough time to build any kind of shelter with a light source. On top of this my attacks stop doing damage at about half health. And HP regeneration is next to none. Any tips on what can I do differently?

Comment: Do you know you can get charcoal to craft torches by smelting wood logs?

Comment: This is disabled in "Better than wolves"

Answer (score 10):

If pure survival is all you're looking for, you can almost always survive a night by digging a 3x1 hole, jumping in, and replacing a dirt block above your head.

Be careful of creepers in the morning.

Edited to Add: If you can't produce a light source, then most attempts at nighttime productivity are pretty much doomed. If you can be productive indoors, then there is a limited range aroudn a player (24 blocks) that monsters can't spawn in, so a 25x25 floorplan building can be used without a light source. Be careful about this though, if you leave this building for any reason before you have lit it, you might be coming home to a ambush.

Comment: What if I want to be a little more productive during the night?

Comment: @clorz Good luck there, unless you find something to do in your hidey-hole. The best thing to do is wait until morning, anything else would expose you to attack.

Comment: @clorz added some extra details, but you still can't do much.

Comment: If you can make torches you can spend the night mining, just be sure to leave torches along your path.

Answer (score 3):

One of the best things i could suggest is building a house that's 5/6 blocks ABOVE ground level, Using ladders to climb up to it. That way any mobs that do spawn and come after you during the night can't shoot through any gaps you have to leave due to lack of resources/time/ect.

The very first thing i ALWAYS do when i'm playing survival is cut down as many trees as possible and gather plenty of stone, Always keep a block or 2 of the logs (not turning them to planks) so you can put them in the furnace and create charcoal, That way you can make torches without having to find actual coal which is often difficult to find at the most inappropriate times.

Plus you can make yourself a decent sword then just incase you do have to defend your home

Comment: This proved useful, thanks. Although charcoal is disabled in this mode and coal to torch rate is 1 to 1. But I was lucky enough to spawn in a jungle so I'm living on a tree now =)

Comment: Haha that would have been my next suggestion, Coal is pretty common in jungle biomes you just need to make sure you don't get lost on your way back, If you don't have the Rei's minimap mod you can do what i usually do which is cover the tree in torches, Then place torches down in an arrow shape leading back to your tree every now and again :) (Or use gravel, some form of block that stands out from it's surroundings)

Answer (score 0):

Having played and died a lot in BetterThanWolves, I can say the following. Until you have a sword and actual armour there is nothing you can fight.

Night time is for staying in doors, cooking up the food you find, making tools and mining up cobblestone. Only once the mobs are thoroughly burned by the sun is it safe to come out. Even then a single Creeper will still ruin your day.

The mod is very unforgiving when it comes to combat, once you get hit you are on a loosing battle and your first thoughts must be on survival and escape from that situation.

Your first night will be spent staring out of a small window at a dim moon. Only by the second day do you have enough time to make a furnace to cook food and make light. Sometimes not even then.

Once food is less of a priority, finding coal and therefore lighting will become the next priority.

Answer (score -1):

Well to start, i would get about a trees worth of wood, make those in to planks and you will have around 24 planks, then make a crafting table, make sticks, make a pick and mine some stone (dig into a mountain or dig down) then make stone tools, its about have way to night then a would get some food and get at least a few more logs and mine into a mountain then make charcoal (by smelting in a furnace logs) and stay the for the night and there you go! :D

Comment: This is basically the first thing that comes to mind and it's not working because there is no charcoal in this mod. And mobs are harder to kill with less light sources. What's working is burning logs in a furnace as a light source and sitting on top of a tree or in a tiny hole in the ground.

Comment: @clorz Well, i just looked in to the mod and i thought that you where talking about doggy talents mod, I apologize for not reading it correctly.